# Is an automatic login with Windows scheduled task possible?

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I need to run a python script every day at a certain time. Said script takes screenshots and sends them to me in the mail. I have a .bat that executes the script, and I have created a scheduled task to execute the script, the problem is that if the user is not logged in, the screenshots fail.

Is there any way to do an automatic login with username and password through a Windows scheduled task at a specific time?

I have been reading and it is not clear to me, it seems that not, but I was sure that something like this could be done.

---

This is the scheduled task that I currently have. I need that before it is executed, it is logged in with the user.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1214736/windows-10-scheduled-tasks-with-workstation-lock-unlock-not-being-triggered